# MVC 3 - Passing model to controller from different controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

At the moment this is what I have in my `HomeController`:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(HomeFormViewModel model)
{
    ...
    ...

    TempData["Suppliers"] = service.Suppliers(model.CategoryId, model.LocationId);

    return View("Suppliers");
}
```

This is what I have in my `SupplierController`:

```
public ViewResult Index()
{
    SupplierFormViewModel model = new SupplierFormViewModel();
    model.Suppliers = TempData["Suppliers"] as IEnumerable<Supplier>;

    return View(model);
}
```

This is my `Supplier` `Index.cshtml`:

`@model MyProject.Web.FormViewModels.SupplierFormViewModel`

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Suppliers) {
  ...
  ...
}
```

Instead of using `TempData` is there a different way to pass objects to a different controller and its view?

Comment: Why can't the SupplierController call `service.Suppliers()` for itself?

Comment: @Jeroen I've updated the question and added that `service.Suppliers()` takes properties from `HomeFormViewModel`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why don't you just pass those two ID's in as parameters, then call the service class from the other controller? Something like:

Have your `SupplierController` method like so:

```
public ViewResult Index(int categoryId, int locationId)
{
    SupplierFormViewModel model = new SupplierFormViewModel();
    model.Suppliers = service.Suppliers(categoryId, locationId);

    return View(model);
}
```

Then, I'm assuming you're calling your view from within the `Supplier` view via a link of some sort? You can do:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Suppliers) 
{
    @Html.ActionLink(item.SupplierName, "Index", "Supplier", new { categoryId = item.CategoryId, locationId = item.LocationId})
    //The above assumes item has a SupplierName of course, replace with the
    //text you want to display in the link
}
```

Comment: Gotcha! I knew this, I'm just way too tired to be writing any proper code.

Comment: LOL I hear ya, sounds like Friday syndrome :)